# ubuntu software center is not opening

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. my Ubuntu software is not opening.I tried opening it through the terminal.When I type 'open Ubuntu software center', it shows 'Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console'.
Please give me a solution.

Comment: Have you tried running the command with sudo before it?

Answer (score 0):

Try type `software-center` on terminal. If the terminal says that it is not installed, install it by tipping `sudo apt install software-center`. 
Then go on the icon of your ubuntu center and unlock from launcher and finally go to usr/share/application and drag the ubuntu software center on the launcher.

I have the same problem and in this way I solved it.